# writing jquery with coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

How do I write this on coffeescript?  I can't get the second function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.box_container').hover(function(){   
            var width = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;  
            $(this).find('.left').animate({ right :0  },{queue:false,duration:300});  
            $(this).find('.right').animate({ left :0  },{queue:false,duration:300});  
        }, function(){  

            $(this).find('.left').animate({ right : width},{queue:false,duration:300});  
            $(this).find('.right').animate({ left : width},{queue:false,duration:300});  

        });  

});
```

Comment: You posted javascript right?   Can you post your .coffee too?

Comment: Are you aware of http://js2coffee.org/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready ->
    arg1 = ->   
        width = $(this).outerWidth() / 2
        $(this).find('.left').animate { right :0  },{queue:false,duration:300}  
        $(this).find('.right').animate { left :0  },{queue:false,duration:300} 
    arg2 = ->
        $(this).find('.left').animate { right : width}, {queue:false,duration:300} 
        $(this).find('.right').animate { left : width}, {queue:false,duration:300}  

    $('.box_container').hover arg1, arg2
```

I would do it like this (I like to keep the parens for the jQuery functions because I think the chaining becomes unreadable without them)

Comment: this way you store these functions globaly

Comment: Not globally, within the document.ready function scope.  It's not an exact translation, I pulled the functions out and named them for clarity, but for the current sample it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional coffeescript for your mentioned code will look something like:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.box_container').hover ->
      width = $(@).outerWidth()/2
      $(@).find('.left').animate
        right: 0
       ,
        queue:false
        duration: 3000
      $(@).find('.right').animate
        left: 0
       ,
        queue:false
        duration: 3000

   ,
    ->
      $(@).find('.left').animate
        right: width
       ,
        queue: false
        duration: 3000
      $(@).find('.right').animate
        left: width
       ,
        queue: false
        duration: 3000
```

Here is the [link with side-by-side JS view](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%0AjQuery%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24%28%27.box_container%27%29.hover%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20width%20=%20%24%28@%29.outerWidth%28%29/2%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28@%29.find%28%27.left%27%29.animate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20right%3a%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20queue%3afalse%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20duration%3a%203000%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28@%29.find%28%27.right%27%29.animate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20left%3a%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20queue%3afalse%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20duration%3a%203000%0A%0A%20%20%20,%0A%20%20%20%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28@%29.find%28%27.left%27%29.animate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20right%3a%20width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20queue%3a%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20duration%3a%203000%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28@%29.find%28%27.right%27%29.animate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20left%3a%20width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20queue%3a%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20duration%3a%203000). I do understand that it looks very complicated than the original JS itself.

So, here goes the simplistic coffeescript with parens, this also denotes how second function can be incorporated.

```
jQuery ->
  $('.box_container').hover ->
      width = $(@).outerWidth()/2
      $(@).find('.left').animate({right: 0}, {queue:false, duration: 3000 });
      $(@).find('.right').animate({left: 0}, {queue:false, duration: 3000 });
   ,
    ->
      $(@).find('.left').animate({right: width}, {queue: false, duration: 3000});
      $(@).find('.right').animate({left: width}, {queue: false, duration: 3000});
```

Happy coffey-ing :)

Answer (score 0):

Parens make this simpler.

```
$('.box_container').hover(
  ->
    # function one content
    doStuff()

  ->
    # function two content
    doMoreStuff()
)
```